# TCL regexp not returning expected matches

Tags: regex, tcl

I am extracting numerical data of voltages from a file name. The name contains three such data but regexp is only returning 2.

```
set data "blabla_0p500v_0p530v_0p550v_m25c_foo.dat"
regexp -all -inline {_(\dp\d{3})v_} $data
```

Returns:

```
_0p500v_ 0p500 _0p550v_ 0p550
```

I was expecting :

```
_0p500v_ 0p500 _0p530v_ 0p530 _0p550v_ 0p550
```

Not sure what's missing.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It seems that you could use `regexp -all -inline {\dp\d{3}} $data` to get the matches directly.

Comment: @PeterLewerin Then, it is not known if the match occurred in between underscores (unless you add some code for that).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: obviously. And, from the example, that doesn't seem to matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a positive lookahead:

```
_(\dp\d{3})v(?=_)
```

This way following underscore is not consumed and is ready to be matched by next iteration.

To append `_` in matched part:

```
set output [regexp -all -inline {_(\dp\d{3})v(?=_)} $data]
set index 0
foreach item $output {
  puts [expr {$index % 2 == 0 ? "$item\_": $item}]
  incr index
}
```

[Live demo](https://ideone.com/iwfeob)

Comment: I like this one best. I don't need the 'v_' in the capture but want to have it part of the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You may use your pattern, but iterate over the string searching for all occurrences of the first char, `_` (note it can be done with a regex using `-indices` option if the first char is not "hardcoded", but here you may use a mere `string first`), and check for a regex match at each of those locations. If a match is found, `lappend` the match and the first capture into the list.

See the [Tcl code demo](https://ideone.com/ypmWeu):

```
set data "blabla_0p500v_0p530v_0p550v_m25c_foo.dat"
set RE {_(\dp\d{3}v)_}
set result []
set idx [string first "_" $data 0]
while {$idx > -1} {
    if {[regexp -start $idx $RE $data whole between]==1} {
        lappend result $whole $between
    }
    set idx [string first "_" $data $idx+1]
}
puts $result
```

Output:

```
_0p500v_ 0p500v _0p530v_ 0p530v _0p550v_ 0p550v
```

Note you may use [@revo's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50259929/3832970), but you will have to reconstruct the output by examining all the items in the resulting list and appending `_` to those items that start with `_`:

```
set data "blabla_0p500v_0p530v_0p550v_m25c_foo.dat"
set RE {_(\dp\d{3}v)(?=_)}
set ms [regexp -all -inline $RE $data]
set result []
foreach m $ms {
    if {[string index $m 0] == "_"} {
        lappend result "${m}_"
    } else {
        lappend result $m
    }
}
puts $result
```

See [another Tcl demo online](https://ideone.com/hOhNJY).

Just to clarify what "does not consume" here means: `(?=_)`, a non-cosuming pattern, does not put the `_` into the regex match value, and the regex index stay right before `_` when the lookahead pattern is executed. Thus, the next match can start right before this `_`.